# How to initialize an int buried 2 levels deep inside typdef'd unions

Tags: c, struct, typedef, bit-fields, unions

I would like to perform the following

```
static Type2 MyData;
MyData.Base.Data = (0b0000000000010100);
```

as a static initialization. For example

```
static Type2 MyData = (typecast)(0b0000000000010100);
```

What would I typecast this with? 
Here are the typedefs for Type1 and Type2

```
typedef union
{
    UINT16 Data;
    struct
    {
        unsigned      :10;  
        unsigned var1 :3;   
        unsigned var2 :2;   
        unsigned var3 :1;   
    };
} Type1;    

typedef union
{
    Type1 Base;     
    struct
    {
        unsigned var4 :3;
        unsigned var5 :2;   
        unsigned      :11;
    } Data;
} Type2;
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a cast? Can't you do it within the type system?

Comment: I get an invalid initialization error. the compiler cannot automatically cast from scalar to non scalar types

Comment: No, what I mean is that you don't cast at all. Use standard struct/union initialization syntax to initialize memberwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676047/how-to-initialize-a-const-variable-inside-a-struct-in-c#4676129), try `Type2 t = { .Base.Data = 0x18 };` If your goal is to set the bitfields in `Type1` you should probably call them out directly; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087057/c-union-and-bitfields).